# Unable to access the Internet at Starbucks - used to work with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

For close to 6 months I haven't been able to have access to the Internet with the Starbucks wifi.

Ubuntu sees the Wifi and is able to establish a connection. But then when I click access/accept... it does some redirection and then just doesn't do anything. It looks like it just hangs.

I suspect that it is a dnsmasq issue but I am unsure.

I used to have Ubuntu 16.04 now 17.10. When I had the older version the Internet worked perfectly. Not anymore.

- [dnsmasq in Ubuntu 16.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/dnsmasq) is 2.75
- [dnsmasq in Ubuntu 17.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/dnsmasq) is 2.78

I tried `tcpdump`. I got more than 700k rows of logs out of it. Plus I don't understand most of it. Here is a sample:

```
18:04:26.564268 IP 10.0.9.137.49266 > 192.190.0.106.http: Flags [.], ack 20161, win 544, options [nop,nop,TS val 1641878439 ecr 315460744], length 0
18:04:26.564273 IP 192.190.0.106.http > 10.0.9.137.49266: Flags [.], seq 20161:21601, ack 1282, win 62, options [nop,nop,TS val 315460744 ecr 1641878430], length 1440: HTTP
18:04:26.564277 IP 10.0.9.137.49266 > 192.190.0.106.http: Flags [.], ack 21601, win 567, options [nop,nop,TS val 1641878439 ecr 315460744], length 0
18:04:26.564438 IP localhost.37212 > localhost.domain: 29983+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
18:04:26.564473 IP localhost.35985 > localhost.domain: 10794+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
18:04:26.564496 IP localhost.domain > localhost.46709: 30654 0/0/1 (56)
18:04:26.564514 IP localhost.domain > localhost.44492: 24516 0/0/1 (56)
18:04:26.564519 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port 44492 unreachable, length 92
18:04:26.564664 IP localhost.35882 > localhost.domain: 64112+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
18:04:26.564690 IP localhost.32892 > localhost.domain: 14648+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
18:04:26.564718 IP localhost.domain > localhost.48486: 47788 0/0/1 (56)
18:04:26.564737 IP localhost.domain > localhost.40167: 14148 0/0/1 (56)
18:04:26.564741 IP localhost > localhost: ICMP localhost udp port 40167 unreachable, length 92
18:04:26.564861 IP 192.190.0.106.http > 10.0.9.137.49266: Flags [.], seq 21601:27361, ack 1282, win 62, options [nop,nop,TS val 315460744 ecr 1641878430], length 5760: HTTP
18:04:26.564868 IP 10.0.9.137.49266 > 192.190.0.106.http: Flags [.], ack 27361, win 657, options [nop,nop,TS val 1641878440 ecr 315460744], length 0
18:04:26.564940 IP localhost.56634 > localhost.domain: 33651+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
18:04:26.564971 IP localhost.26306 > localhost.domain: 12045+ [1au] AAAA? starbucks-east.datavalet.io. (56)
```

The ICMP seems to be called a lot. Something is doing many pings on different ports.

Details about my system:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
```

This might be related: [The Problem with Connecting to Public WiFi on Linux - Medium](https://medium.com/@iospadov/the-problem-with-connecting-to-public-wifi-on-linux-20cebc740c6a)

Another detail: sometimes I am able to get the Internet. But it's random.

Comment: Are you using firefox or chromium?  What browser are you using? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: FireFox, Google Chrome, and Chromium. The browser doesn't change anything. And I have been trying different things in the last 6 months.

Comment: Can you ping Google's DNS servers? `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: `8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6993ms`

Comment: Have you tried this - [Can't connect to Starbucks wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005628/cant-connect-to-starbucks-wifi/1020934#1020934)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend was able to resolve it.

In the settings for Starbucks WIFI go to IPv4 configurations tab.

Turn off Automatic for the DNS.

Then add these nameservers in the input: `10.0.9.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`

`10.0.9.1` might be different in other StarBucks. This IP is the one of the router.

**UPDATE**

You might need to modify: /etc/resolv.conf

With:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 10.0.9.1
```

Again the `10.0.9.1` is the IP of the Wifi router.

Comment: Didn't work. How did you get the router IP?

Answer (score 2):

This tends to happen because places like Starbucks will use a captive portal, and not allow connections out (save some rare exceptions) until you authenticate with the network. In Starbucks' case, this means agreeing to a terms of service.

In your web browser, you may usually be able to navigate to any non-HTTPS domain (for example, `http://captive.apple.com/` or `http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt`, both of which are "captive portal" detection systems used by Apple and Windows, respectively).

In some cases, the captive portals will *also* block DNS requests going out. In this case, you can just directly connect to any IP address on the public net that isn't protected by HTTPS. I tend to use `91.189.91.23`, which is the IP address of Canonical's APT mirrors.

While you could change your DNS, there are some cases where this is undesirable and a privacy concern - for example, Starbucks tracking what sites you visit through DNS.

Comment: Just to clarify where do you use the `91.189.91.23` IP?

Comment: @jnbdz I just type it straight into my web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I did what jnbdz recommended, but it didn't work with Ubuntu 20.04.
However, I was able to find out the URL of the captive portal by doing this:

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo apt install net-tools`

gives error message
E: Failed to fetch https:/ /sbux-portal.globalreachtech.com/?login_url=https://n438.network-auth.com/splash/login? etc.

I copied this URL and pasted it into a browser

After that, the captive portal showed up, and I was able to gain Internet access at Starbucks.

Comment: They might be using another service for their captive portal where you are or maybe they are some new updates to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the post so that people don't think that this is the actual URL. My goal was to give a method to find the captive portal URL. Do you happen to know a better method of finding the URL when the computer is stuck between connected to the Wifi but not pulling up the captive portal?

Answer (score 0):

I just found another method that works for me:

Enable Connectivity Checking in Settings.
[image]

This will pull up the captive portal at Starbucks.
(Read this somewhere on SO but now can't find the page anymore)

Comment: Here is a [reference](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/disable-network-connectivity-checking-ubuntu-17-10). Feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: My question is a few years old. So since than I imagine Ubuntu came up with the solution you are presenting. Thanks for the input.