# Detecting whether my wireless card supports mac address spoofing?

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

In order to get around an [issue with Starbucks WIFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023429/cant-connect-to-google-starbucks-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-10) someone suggested spoofing my network cards mac address.  How do I detect whether the wifi card supports mac address spoofing?

There is material out there on this, but it is very dated.  How do you do this on Ubuntu 17.10?

I ended up just running this:

```
sudo macchanger --mac 00:11:22:33:44:55 wlan0
```

Use `iwconfig` to detect the name of your wireless card.  Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue with Starbucks WIFI.

Comment: Indeed! Please see: https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/xchange-ubuntu-linux-mac-address-with-network-manager.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.etyhI1MjnA.png

Comment: How do you do it on Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) if I was worried about revealing my MAC address to a random network. Everything is pretty much done for you and the devs are extremely paranoid (this is not a bad thing obviously). MAC address spoofing is [enabled by default](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/mac_spoofing/index.en.html#index2h1) upon boot.

This is probably overkill just to spoof in Starbucks however. :)

Sorry I can't help you on how to spoof in Ubuntu as I use Kubuntu, I haven't used Ubuntu since they dropped gnome but there used to be an option in the network device configuration GUI.

Comment: I do want to reveal my mac address.  The issue I'm having is that Starbucks's router contacts a service before allowing you access and if that service already has your email address it just spins forever ... so someone suggested spoofing my ip address, so it's good to know whether my laptop supports that before i get into this situation again ...

Comment: There's an application called macchanger which I recall using a while back and was fairly straightforward. Here is more info: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/macchanger-utility-for-manipulating-the-mac-address-of-network-interfaces-included-gui-utility.html it also includes a gui version for added user-friendliness (macchanger-gtk).